# How to allow only certain cyclic dependencies in ArchUnit?

Tags: archunit

In ArchUnit, I can check that packages `.should().beFreeOfCycles()`. How can I specify exceptions to this rule for certain cycles?

E.g., given these packages and their dependencies:

```
A <-> B <-> C
```

How can I allow `A <-> B`, but still forbid `A` and `B` being part of any other cycle, e.g. `B <-> C`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Freezing Arch Rules](https://www.archunit.org/userguide/html/000_Index.html#_freezing_arch_rules) is always an option to allow for certain violations, but catch others.
Would that be feasible in your case?

Comment: Thanks. It is not convenient but seems to work. I have posted my code as [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70423544/443836).

Answer (score 1):

Based on [Manfred](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13134095)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70420850/443836), here is a solution that seems to work fine (implemented in Kotlin):

```kotlin
fun test() {
    SlicesRuleDefinition.slices().matching("(com.mypackage.*..)")
        .should()
        // Using an extension method which allows us to specify allowed
        // cycles succinctly:
        .beFreeOfCyclesExcept("com.mypackage.a" to "com.mypackage.b")
        .check(someClasses)
}

fun SlicesShould.beFreeOfCyclesExcept(
    vararg allowed: Pair<String, String>
): ArchRule =
    FreezingArchRule
        // In case you are not familiar with Kotlin:
        // We are in an extension method. 'this' will be substituted with
        // 'SlicesRuleDefinition.slices().matching("(com.mypackage.*..)")
        // .should()';
        .freeze(this.beFreeOfCycles())
        .persistIn(
            // Using a custom ViolationStore instead of the default 
            // TextFileBasedViolationStore so we can configure the
            // allowed violations in code instead of a text file:
            object : ViolationStore {

                override fun initialize(properties: Properties) {}

                override fun contains(rule: ArchRule): Boolean = true

                override fun save(rule: ArchRule, violations: List<String>) {
                    // Doing nothing here because we do not want ArchUnit 
                    // to add any additional allowed violations.
                }

                override fun getViolations(rule: ArchRule): List<String> =
                    allowed
                        // ArchUnit records cycles in the form 
                        // A -> B -> A. I.e., A -> B -> A and 
                        // B -> A -> B are different violations.
                        // We add the reverse cycle to make sure
                        // both directions are allowed:
                        .flatMap { pair -> 
                            listOf(pair, Pair(pair.second, pair.first)) 
                        }
                        // .distinct() is not necessary, but using it is
                        // cleaner because by adding the reverse cycles
                        // we may possibly have added duplicates:
                        .distinct()
                        .map { (sliceA, sliceB) ->
                            // This is a prefix of the format that
                            // ArchUnit uses:
                            "Cycle detected: Slice $sliceA -> \n" +
                                "                Slice $sliceB -> \n" +
                                "                Slice $sliceA\n"
                        }
            }
        )
        // The lines that ArchUnit uses are very specific, including 
        // info about which methods etc. create the cycle. That is 
        // exactly what is desirable when establishing a baseline for 
        // legacy code. But we want to permanently allow certain 
        // cycles, regardless of which current or future code creates 
        // the cycle. Thus, we only compare the prefixes of violation
        // lines:
        .associateViolationLinesVia { 
            lineFromFirstViolation,
            lineFromSecondViolation ->
                lineFromFirstViolation.startsWith(lineFromSecondViolation)
        }
```

Note that I have tested this only on a small project.

Comment: My suggestion was to wrap your rule with [`FreezingArchRule.freeze`](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.tngtech.archunit/archunit/latest/com/tngtech/archunit/library/freeze/FreezingArchRule.html#freeze(com.tngtech.archunit.lang.ArchRule)) – `freeze( slices().matching("(com.mypackage.*..)").should().beFreeOfCycles() )` – and put the allowed cycle in the `TextFileBasedViolationStore`.

Comment: Using the default `TextFileBasedViolationStore` instead of a custom `ViolationStore` would work. But instead of generating the actual violation line from the concise representation `"com.mypackage.a" to "com.mypackage.b"` you would need to manually enter the verbose `Cycle detected: Slice com.mypackage.a -> `(...) (and additionally - just in case - also the liine for the inverted direction) into a text file.

Comment: To avoid confusion: Your `freeze(slices().matching("(com.mypackage.*..)").should().beFreeOfCycles())` is exactly was is happening here. I just didn't use the static import for `SlicesRuleDefinition.slices()`, and in my extension method `beFreeOfCyclesExcept()`, `this` will be substituted with `SlicesRuleDefinition.slices().matching("(com.mypackage.*..)").should()`.

Comment: Right. I just wanted to say that I'd use the default `TextFileBasedViolationStore`. You don't have to add any lines manually; ArchUnit can be [configured](https://www.archunit.org/userguide/html/000_Index.html#_configuration) to set up the store during the first test execution (`freeze.store.default.allowStoreCreation=true`).

Comment: That's true. Of course, then you cannot set up any allowed cycles in advance. And there may also be the possibility that ArchUnit will detect a cycle in reverse in the future, which will then be regarded as a different violation (A -> B -> A vs. B -> A -> B).

Comment: I have added comments for clarification to my answer.